# Background Image ::placeholder::before

Tags: css

I want to put an icon to the placeholder of an input like:

```
.vue-input input {
    &::placeholder::before{
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: .75rem;
        width: 1.5rem;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        background-image: url(~/assets/flag-ch.png);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-position: center;
    }
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you don't. The element `inpute` don't have content.

Comment: So it's not valid to call ::before on the placeholder pseudo class?

Comment: for input - yes. But you can wrap your `input` on tag `label` with the same id like in input and solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an icon functioning as a "placeholder" and to disappear when the user starts typing, I suggest you use Javascript, not CSS. Add the Icon and edit its style with Javascript on the Input event listener

Answer (score 0):

On this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) you can find out what can you use for styling placeholder.

And this is the solution to your problem:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="myInput" 
    placeholder="Some Fallback Text" >
```

```
#myInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/114/579/png-transparent-pink-cross-stroke-ink-brush-pen-red-ink-brush-ink-leave-the-material-text.png");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#myInput::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/114/579/png-transparent-pink-cross-stroke-ink-brush-pen-red-ink-brush-ink-leave-the-material-text.png");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#myInput:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/114/579/png-transparent-pink-cross-stroke-ink-brush-pen-red-ink-brush-ink-leave-the-material-text.png");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#myInput:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10- */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/114/579/png-transparent-pink-cross-stroke-ink-brush-pen-red-ink-brush-ink-leave-the-material-text.png");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```